# Cannot deserialize instance of <DataModel> out of START_OBJECT token

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I am facing with problem with Spring and Jackson. I was trying to fetch the input from [this API](https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&maxradiuskm=2000.0&latitude=30.21&longitude=12.9). I've created Java model using  http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

The model is

```
package io.github.mat3e.earthquake.jsonObject;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

import java.util.List;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "type",
    "metadata",
    "features",
    "bbox"
})
public class DataModel {

    @JsonProperty("type")
    private String type;
    @JsonProperty("metadata")
    private Metadata metadata;
    @JsonProperty("features")
    private List<Feature> features = null;
    @JsonProperty("bbox")
    private List<Double> bbox = null;

    @JsonProperty("type")
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    @JsonProperty("type")
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @JsonProperty("metadata")
    public Metadata getMetadata() {
        return metadata;
    }

    @JsonProperty("metadata")
    public void setMetadata(Metadata metadata) {
        this.metadata = metadata;
    }

    @JsonProperty("features")
    public List<Feature> getFeatures() {
        return features;
    }

    @JsonProperty("features")
    public void setFeatures(List<Feature> features) {
        this.features = features;
    }

    @JsonProperty("bbox")
    public List<Double> getBbox() {
        return bbox;
    }

    @JsonProperty("bbox")
    public void setBbox(List<Double> bbox) {
        this.bbox = bbox;
    }

}
```

Of course all dependencies (subclasses are appended in the same strture).

Code to fetch data from external API is;

```
@GetMapping("/3")
    public String getCostam() {
        RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();

        ResponseEntity<DataModel[]> responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(url2, DataModel[].class);
        Object[] objects = responseEntity.getBody();
        MediaType contentType = responseEntity.getHeaders().getContentType();
        HttpStatus statusCode = responseEntity.getStatusCode();
        return statusCode.toString();

    }
```

When I run the code and I am trying to get for adress "api/3" following error occurs:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `[Lio.github.DataModel;` out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
```

Comment: Your error comes from the line: `ResponseEntity<DataModel[]> responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(url2, DataModel[].class);` Looks like the response is NOT an Array of `DataModel`

Comment: Yes it is not an array.
Try  DataModel[].class instead of DataModel.class

Comment: Everything works. Thanks for your help. What can I do more?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Willem and @mkarasik for your help:

I made following changes in code

```
@GetMapping("/3")
    public String getCostam() {
        RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();

        ResponseEntity<DataModel> responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(url2, DataModel.class);

        MediaType contentType = responseEntity.getHeaders().getContentType();
        HttpStatus statusCode = responseEntity.getStatusCode();

        System.out.println(responseEntity
                .getBody().getFeatures());



        return statusCode.toString();

    }
```

To get an array of places where earthquake took place I just ovverided method in Feature class

```
 @Override
    public String toString() {
        return properties.getPlace();
    }
```

Thanks guys for you help. I got what I needed.

Now I want to map parameters from FrontEnd to provide it to my backend instead of hardcoded String.